# Can the error term variance ever be estimated without fitting a regression line in a basic linear regression model?

Tags: probability, statistics, mean-square-error

Can the error term variance ever be estimated without fitting a regression line in a basic linear regression model? I don't understand how this would be possible and why. Because wouldn't you always need the mean square error for that? And for the mean square error, you would need the estimated Y values and hence the regression line?